# How do I pull apart Case Classes filled with Options in Scala

Tags: scala, case-class, scala-option

I'm very new to Scala and I'm still trying to get used to the syntax and style, so this is probably a very simple question.

I'm working with a codebase where there are lots of case classes populated with Options like so:

```
case class Person(
  pants: Option[Pants]
)
case class Pants(
  pocket: Option[Pocket]
)
case class Pocket(
  cash: Option[Cash]
)
case class Cash(
  value: String = "zilch"
)
```

In the example above, how would you go about returning how much money is in a `Person`'s `Pants` `Pocket`, if they are indeed wearing pants... with pockets, and if they have any money at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A great time for [for-comprehensions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html):

```
val someCash: Option[Cash] =
   for( pants  <- somePerson.pants;
        pocket <- pants.pocket;
        cash   <- pocket.cash ) yield cash
```

Equivalently you can write the following, for which the first code is syntactic sugar (ignoring some subtleties):

```
val someCash: Option[Cash] = 
   somePerson.pants.flatMap(_.pocket.flatMap(_.cash))
```

(I'm not totally sure if you can write the last expression using the `_` wildcards, as I did).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The for-comprehension approach is actually exactly what I was trying to do, but the structure I'm working with is not as clean as the example I gave above. At least this confirms I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 12):

Scalaz 7 has changed a little so here is another example:

```
  object PartialLensExample extends App {

  import scalaz._
  import Lens._
  import PLens._


  case class Bar(blub: Option[String])
  case class Foo(bar: Option[Bar])

  // normal lenses for getting and setting values
  val fooBarL: Foo @> Option[Bar] = lensg(foo ⇒ bar ⇒ foo.copy(bar = bar), _.bar)
  val barBlubL: Bar @> Option[String] = lensg(bar ⇒ blub ⇒ bar.copy(blub = blub), _.blub)

  // compose the above as 'Partial Lenses', >=> is just an alias for 'andThen'
  val fooBarBlubL: Foo @?> String = fooBarL.partial >=> somePLens >=> barBlubL.partial >=> somePLens

  // try it
  val foo = Foo(Some(Bar(Some("Hi"))))

  println(fooBarBlubL.get(foo)) // Some(Hi)

  println(fooBarBlubL.set(foo, "Bye")) //Foo(Some(Bar(Some(Bye))))

  // setting values
  val foo2 = Foo(None)
  println(fooBarL.set(foo2, Some(Bar(None)))) // Foo(Some(Bar(None)))

}
```

Comment: Great answer, but a big stumbling block here when setting those nested values is: what if any values are `None`? The `PLens` in your example will only allow `blub: Option[String]` to be assigned if `blub` _already has `Some` value_. I've found monadic state transitions can initialize top-level members, but I'm unclear how that'd be done for those further down.

Comment: hmm, yes. I updated the answer for setting a Bar on a Foo, but I see the issue of setting the blub value in Bar - I'll need to ponder on that.

Comment: [A bogosity of state transitions using `PLens` instances](https://gist.github.com/michaelahlers/20ec194410f89422847fdd3a71777c69) is the best I could do, initializing properties as needed (which makes sense, especially in light of [the answer involving pants](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9978488/700420) @ben-james gave). This strikes me as too laborious and it doesn't scale, so I imagine there's got to be a better approach.

Comment: Having thought about this I think the behaviour is correct as it is. This problem boils down to a lens setting a value on an Option. If the Option is None then there is nothing to set. However, I can also see that it would be useful for a lens to support setting a value in an Option contained by another type, as a shorthand perhaps. As it stands you need to set the Option as a whole.

Answer (score 6):

The question didn't mention *modifying* the data, but when you need to do this you quickly find the Scala library doesn't have the tools to make this easy (when the data is immutable). If you haven't experienced this yet, try writing a function which will replace, or modify, the `value` of the `Cash` held by a `Person`, using the types defined in the question.

As described in Tony Morris' [Asymmetric Lenses in Scala](http://dropbox.tmorris.net/media/doc/lenses.pdf), *lenses* are an appropriate solution to this problem.

Here's an example of how we can access and update the `value` of a person's `Cash` using the `Lens` and `PLens` (partial lens) implementations from the [scalaz-seven](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven) branch of Scalaz.

First, some boilerplate: define the Lens instance for each field of the case classes. `A @-@ B` means the same as `Lens[A, B]`.

```
val pants: Person @-@ Option[Pants] =
  lensG(_.pants, p => ps => p.copy(pants = ps))

val pocket: Pants @-@ Option[Pocket] =
  lensG(_.pocket, ps => p => ps.copy(pocket = p))

val cash: Pocket @-@ Option[Cash] =
  lensG(_.cash, p => c => p.copy(cash = c))

val value: Cash @-@ String =
  lensG(_.value, c => v => c.copy(value = v))
```

We can't compose all of these lenses, however, because most of the fields are wrapped in `Option` types.

*Partial Lenses* to the rescue: these allow us to access and update parts of a structure that *may not exist*, such as the `Some` value of an `Option`, or the `head` of a `List`.

We can use the `somePLens` function from Scalaz 7 to create a partial lens viewing each optional field. In order to compose a partial lens with one of our regular lenses, however, we need to access the equivalent partial lens instance for the regular lens, using the `partial` method that exists on every `Lens`.

```
// @-? is an infix type alias for PLens
val someCash: Pocket @-? Cash = cash.partial andThen somePLens

scala> someCash.get(Pocket(Some(Cash("zilch"))))
res1: Option[Cash] = Some(Cash(zilch))
```

In the same way, we can create our partial lens viewing the cash held by a `Person` by composing all our lenses' `partial` instances, and sandwiching instances of `somePLens`. Here, I've used the `<=<` operator, an alias for `andThen` (which is equivalent to `compose` with the operands switched).

```
val someCashValue: Person @-? String =
  pants.partial <=< somePLens <=<
  pocket.partial <=< somePLens <=<
  cash.partial <=< somePLens <=<
  value.partial
```

Creating a `Person` instance to play with:

```
val ben = Person(Some(Pants(Some(Pocket(Some(Cash("zilch")))))))
```

Using the partial lens to access the value of cash I have:

```
scala> someCashValue.get(ben)
res2: Option[String] = Some(zilch)
```

Using the partial lens to modify the value:

```
scala> someCashValue.mod(_ + ", zero, nada", ben)
res3: Person = Person(Some(Pants(Some(Pocket(Some(Cash(zilch, zero, nada)))))))
```

Now, if I'm *not* wearing any pants (!), we can see how an attempt to modify the value of my cash will have no effect:

```
scala> val ben = Person(None)
ben: Person = Person(None)

scala> someCashValue.mod(_ + ", zero, nada", ben)
res4: Person = Person(None)
```

Answer (score 2):

ziggystar's answer is what I would use, but for completeness, pattern matching can also be used, eg,

```
val someCash: Option[Cash] = person match {
  case Person(Some(Pants(Some(Pocket(Some(cash)))))) => Some(cash)
  case _ => None
}
```